# JavaScript expression evaluation error

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date, math

I am using Zeller's Congruence to predict what day of the week a given date falls on. The algorithm will return a value from `0...6`. 0 means Sunday, 1 means Monday, 2 is Tuesday, etc. The algorithm is this:

`Day = ((26M-2)/10 + D + Y + Y/4 + C/4 + 5C) MOD 7`

There is a part of the algorithm that states

```
IF Month < 3 THEN
    Year = Year - 1
    Month = Month + 10
ELSE
    Month = Month - 2
END IF;
```

Where `D` is the day, `Y` is the last two digits of the year, `M` is the month, and `C` is the century which is the first two numbers of the year.

For some reason, when I plug this into javascript I am getting incorrect results. Take the date 2/15/16. This date occurred on a Monday. Here is my code for the algorithm:

`(Math.floor((26 * monthVal) - 2 / 10) + dayVal + yearVal + Math.floor(yearVal / 4) + Math.floor(centuryVal / 4) + (5 * centuryVal)) % 7`

I put in debugging statements to make sure `monthVal`, `dayVal`, `yearVal`, etc were all correct and they are. This expression should evaluate to `1`, but for some reason it evaluates to `0`. When I break it down I get the correct results. So:

`Math.floor(((26 * monthVal) - 2) / 10)` for the date given above comes out to `Math.floor(((26 * 12) - 2) / 10) = 31`

`dayVal = 15`, `yearVal = 15`, `centuryVal = 20`, `Math.floor(yearVal / 4) = 3`, `Math.floor(centuryVal / 4) = 5`, and `(5 * centuryVal) = 100`

If we put all this together we get

`(31 + 15 + 15 + 3 + 5 + 100) % 7 = 1`

When I plug it in the computer with the numbers like I did directly above, it gets the right answer. But when I use the variable names and put them all together like I did 11-12 lines above, the same exact expression comes out to be `0` and I don't know why. How come it's giving me the wrong answer even though when I work it by hand I get the right answer? Am I missing something relating to operation precedence?

Comment: It means variables hold other values. Btw, `(31 + 15 + 15 + 3 + 5 + 20) % 7` does not equal `1`, but `5`

Comment: I put in abunch of debugging statements to show me the values being held in each variable and they all contain the correct values.

Comment: How can you be sure if even with hardcoded numbers you calculated it wrong?

Comment: I made a typo. I fixed it now in the problem. It should have read `(31 + 15 + 15 + 3 + 5 + 100) % 7` which DOES equal 1.

Comment: When I type `(31 + 15 + 15 + 3 + 5 + 100) % 7` directly into the computer, I get `1`, but when I type the full expression with variable names and such, I get `0`. The variables all contain the correct values. I have thoroughly checked using many many debug statements.

Comment: Use `(Math.floor((26 * monthVal - 2) / 10)`, the brackets are in the wrong place.

Comment: @m69 I am, if you look how I typed out everything above I wrote `(Math.floor((26 * monthVal - 2) / 10) + .....`

Comment: There are two different versions in your question.

Comment: The only way it will work in the program is if I put `Math.floor(((26 * monthVal) - 2) / 10)`. If I get rid of the parenthesis after 2 then it evaluates incorrectly.

Comment: Any chance you could post actual code? There's lots of ambiguity in this discussion.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I needed to put `parseInt` around each of the variables. It works correctly now.

Comment: All I know is before I put `parseInt` it wouldn't work, and now that I put it in, I am getting the correct results. I have tried with many different dates to make sure, and it is getting the correct results.

Comment: " 2/15/16" is presumably 15 February, which was indeed a Monday, but `yearVal = 15` should be `yearVal = 16`. Putting those values into the corrected equation gives 5, not 1.

Comment: If you look at the conditions mentioned above then you would see that for month values less than `3`, the you are to decrement the `yearVal` by 1. So yes, the `year` passed into it was `16` but because of the algorithm, we use `15`. It says this in the statement `IF Month < 3 THEN Year = Year - 1...` which putting this value into the equtation gives 1.

Comment: If we were to put in a date like 5/15/16, then `yearVal` would be `16`. But because `2` is less than `3`, we decrement that `yearVal` to `15`

Comment: So you have only partially implemented the algorithm, cool. Your month number should be 12 then.

Comment: Yes, it is `12`. That's how I got `31`. `(26 * 12) - 2) / 10 = 31`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your first expression looks fine (at least for today), if you put a bracket in the position:

```
(Math.floor((26 * monthVal - 2) / 10) + dayVal + yearVal + Math.floor(yearVal / 4) + Math.floor(centuryVal / 4) + (5 * centuryVal)) % 7
```

Note the bracket after 2, not before.

https://jsfiddle.net/7hjw63d3/

Comment: I put the bracket after the 2 and it still doesn't work. It seems like the ONLY way I can get it to work is with `parseInt`

Comment: I've added a link to jsfiddle. With corrected expression and your test data it evaluates to 1, not to 0, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the **whole** algorithm and correcting:

```
Math.floor((26 * monthVal) - 2 / 10)
```

to

```
Math.floor((26 * monthVal - 2) / 10)
```

gives:

```js
// Very simple parser of dates in d/m/y format
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[1]-1, b[0]);
}
  
['15/2/2016','16/2/2016','17/2/2016','18/2/2016','19/2/2016',
 '20/2/2016','21/2/2016','22/2/2016','23/2/2016','24/2/2016',
 '25/2/2016','26/2/2016','27/2/2016','28/2/2016','29/2/2016',
 '1/3/2016','2/3/2016','3/3/2016','4/3/2016','5/3/2016',
 '1/1/2016','30/6/2016','23/10/2016','1/1/2000'].forEach(function(s) {
  var d = parseDMY(s);
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var day = +b[0], 
      month = b[1] - 2,
      cent = b[2]/100|0,
      yr = b[2]%100;
  if (month < 1) {
    month += 12;
    yr -= 1;
  } 
  document.write(d + ' : ' + 
    ((Math.floor((26 * month - 2) / 10) + day + yr + Math.floor(yr / 4) + Math.floor(cent / 4) + (5 * cent)) % 7)
    + '<br>'
  );
})
```

Also, the test values in the OP seem to be incorrect, the year should be 16, not 15.

Comment: You are using the `Date` class which we are not allowed to use. I don't know why but I am telling you this doesn't work for me. I copied and pasted the expression EXACTLY the way you have it and it doesn't work for on my program.

Comment: I am use Date **only** to display the day for the date (the `d = parseDMY()` part), it's not used in any way for the calculation. Only the original string is used for that and it implements your code as you posted it with only the changes noted. Does it work here? If so, then "not working" is a result of your copy and paste. Note that my dates are **day/month/year**, which might be different to yours.